# NVPARSER: HEVC: Seeking is not performed on IRAP picture ( GStreamer )

Tags: gstreamer-1.0, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-deepstream

Device Specification :

**• Hardware Platform (Jetson Xavier NX)
**• Deepstream NGC Container ( DeepStream-l4t container 6.0 samples )
**• JetPack Version 4.6.1 (L4T 32.7.1)
**• CUDA 10.2.300
**• TensorRT Version 8.2.1.8
**• CUDNN : 8.2.1.32

I am trying to run a deepstream application on my device. I get following issue while running my application with my current rtsp.
NVPARSER: HEVC: Seeking is not performed on IRAP picture
I have tested my rtsp with multiple methods. It is working only with cv2 with ffmpeg as a backend with other methods it is giving errors.
The methods I have tried are following.

1. With ffplay and ffmpeg errors are following.

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1193.jpg)

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jewOT.jpg)
2. With gst-launch-1.0 / gst-play-1.0 / gst-discoverer-1.0 I am getting same error as one in deepstream Application.

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT9F2.jpg)

Can someone give me solution to this issue or just explain me the reason for this issue to occur is it related to my rtsp source or some other issue is happening.

Comment: Which gstreamer string are you using? I'm using the following one and it's giving me the same error, maybe it could depend on it.

rtspsrc location={} latency=200 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, width=2880, height=1620, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop